# Promotion code for iOS in-app purchases

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I'd like to offer 100% discounts via one time use coupons on IAPs.  Can it be done?  And more than just 100 of them, which I think is the number of coupons Apple allows.  My goal is to generate future IAPs by introducing players who don't use them to try them.

Comment: Don't think so. Most apps handle this by using tokens the user purchases via IAP and giving users some free tokens when they start out.

Answer (score 6):

From what I've been able to tell, it seems that Apple doesn't officially allow IAP promotion codes.
From: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies

> 1.1 Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected
>
> 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be
>   rejected

See also

1) https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/37264-rejected-by-apple-cause-of-promo-code-custom-solution/

2) [How to create a promotion code for iOS in-app purchases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27219237/how-to-create-a-promotion-code-for-ios-in-app-purchases)

If you still want to power ahead and do this, one way is a URL scheme. Briefly, you enable your app to respond to something like: myAppName://... when that URL is present in an email being read using the Apple Mail app, or when that URL is typed into Safari. Then, your app examines the URL parameters and pulls out, say a code identifying the type of comped purchase (e.g., perhaps consulting a back-end server), and makes the comped purchase available to the user.

See also:

A) [Free iOS in app purchase for some users/devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914086/free-ios-in-app-purchase-for-some-users-devices)

B) [Rewarding iOS app beta testers with in app purchase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892887/rewarding-ios-app-beta-testers-with-in-app-purchase)

C) [iOS In-App Purchase, sending to another account (gifting?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565336/ios-in-app-purchase-sending-to-another-account-gifting)

D) [Providing a discount code for an iOS in-app-purchase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307463/providing-a-discount-code-for-an-ios-in-app-purchase)

Comment: I would, but because I just joined and don't yet have a reputation of 15 or more it won't let me...